# Dask: TimeOut Error When Reading Parquet from S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, dask, amazon-emr, dask-distributed

I'm experiencing some frustrating issues using `Dask-Yarn` on an EMR cluster. I'm trying to read in about 5M+ rows of data from partitioned parquet files stored in S3. I repartition the data across the 800 Dask workers and then persist the data to memory. There is no problem at this point. Then when I use downstream functions to manipulate this data, I start to run into `TimeOut` errors a quarter of the way through the process, which doesn't make sense because I thought I already persisted this data to memory. Does anyone how I can resolve these `timeout` issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also why does it read the parquet files again; I already persisted them to memory?

**Error:**

```
ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://data-files.s3.amazonaws.com/users/rhun/data.parquet/batch%3D0.0/part-00114-811278f0-e6cc-43d4-a38c-2043509029ac.c000.snappy.parquet"
```

**Code Example:**

```py
cluster = YarnCluster(environment='doctype.tar.gz', 
                      worker_memory='12GiB', 
                      worker_vcores=8
                     )
client = Client(cluster)
cluster.scale(800)
df = dd.read_parquet('s3://data-files/users/rhun/data_2022-02-18.parquet/batch=0.0/',
                         columns=['filehash',
                                  'sentences',
                                  'div2style'
                                 ],
                         engine='pyarrow')
df = df.repartition(npartitions=5000).persist()

def calc_pdf_features(df):
    
    files_to_download = df['filehash'].tolist()
    
    AWS_BUCKET = "my_data"

    session = boto3.Session()
    client = session.client("s3")
    func = partial(download_one_file, AWS_BUCKET, client)

    res = []
    successful_downloads = []

    # download pdf files concurrently
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=32) as executor:
        futures = {
            executor.submit(func, file_to_download): file_to_download for file_to_download in files_to_download
        }
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            if future.exception():
                res.append({'filehash': futures[future],
                            'bullet_count': float(0),
                            'item_count': float(0),
                            'colon_count': float(0),
                            'element_tags': [],
                            'max_element_leng': float(0)})
            else:
                successful_downloads.append(futures[future])
        
    def traverse_pdf(fh):
        doc = fitz.open(fh + '.pdf')
        font_counts, styles = fonts(doc, granularity=False)
        size_tag = font_tags(font_counts, styles)
        elements = headers_para(doc, size_tag)
        res.append({'filehash': fh,
                    'bullet_count': float(bullet_counter_row(elements)),
                    'item_count': float(item_counter_row(elements)),
                    'colon_count': float(colon_counter_row(elements)),
                    'element_tags': header_tags(elements),
                    'max_element_leng': max_first3Elements(elements)
                   })

    # extract features from PDF files concurrently 
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=32) as executor:
        futures = {
            executor.submit(traverse_pdf, fh): fh for fh in successful_downloads
        }
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            if future.exception():
                res.append({'filehash': futures[future],
                            'bullet_count': float(0),
                            'item_count': float(0),
                            'colon_count': float(0),
                            'element_tags': [],
                            'max_element_leng': float(0)})
                
    return pd.merge(df, pd.DataFrame(res), on=['filehash'], how='inner')

df = adf.map_partitions(calc_pdf_features, 
                                     meta={'filehash': str,
                                           'sentences': object,
                                           'div2style': object,
                                           'bullet_count': float,
                                           'item_count': float,
                                           'colon_count': float,
                                           'element_tags': object,
                                           'max_element_leng': object
                                          }
                                    )
df.repartition(npartitions=200).to_parquet(
    's3://my-data/DocType_v2/features/batch=0.0/',
    engine='pyarrow')
```

[image]

Comment: the connection timeout does not appear to be for the same file as you are reading in `dd.read_parquet`. Your example is pretty complicated, but it appears you're reading in a list of filepaths from one column in the parquet and then using this list of filepaths to schedule additional read operations using the ThreadPoolExecutor, and one of those is causing the timeout? Please *always* post the full traceback when asking a question on SO.

Answer (score 4):

I have several points what can be a problem, and how to solve it.

- I think it is wrong to do your own Thread Pool inside calc_pdf_features function. If you already delegate parralel processing to the Dask - you should not be doing so. I would try to make your each partition processing single threaded, and than let Dask do the scheduling.
- In order to debug I would put something "very simple" instead of calc_pdf_features and see that everything is working - so you will distinguish problems caused by Dask / AWS etc and timeouts because processing of the partition takes too much time.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your suggestion and refactored my function to be single-threaded. The dask workers always die mid-way through. So frustrating! Now I'm getting an error:

```KilledWorker: ("('assign-e3e7d3da6b20dc687115364c82bef10d', 81)", <WorkerState 'tcp://172.20.47.98:34019', name: dask.worker_515, status: closed, memory: 0, processing: 2>)```

Comment: if you make your function to be "light" , like just counting records , does it work smooth?

Comment: Yep it does. It's when things get heavy, using Dask usually leads to issues

Comment: Ok, so we get one step closer. I see 2 possible problems - timeout (Dask think it takes too long), or, some process die because of memory problems. Lets find what is a cause. 
Can you put also "something similar " in time consumption, but low in memory? 
If it will work - we have memory issue, if not - we need to find place to configure timeouts

Comment: Thanks @David Gruzman - Yeah I can confirm it's a memory leakage. I checked the worker logs. I don't know why it runs out of memory though. Each worker has 16GB of RAM. I would think that's more than enough.

Comment: I posted a snap shot of the dask dashboard. There's a memory leak somewhere in the `calc_pdf_features`, but I'm not sure what's causing it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the code correctly, at the maximum load there are 800 workers, each potentially launching 32 download processes. It's speculation, but this number of requests might exceed the allowed concurrent requests in `s3`, so some of the workers end up waiting for a connection too long.

One way out is to allow a longer wait time before timeout, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48265766/10693596). However, that's still not ideal as you will have workers sitting idle. Instead, the code could be refactored to have a single connection, to avoid nested parallelization, and to let `dask` handle all the downloads and processing.